# Putting HashSet inside a HashMap

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashset

Is there any way to reuse a hash set by adding it to the HashMap, then later changing the HashSet without it changing the previous HashSet that was placed into the hashMap?

```
public static void hash() {
    HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> hset = new HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>(
    HashSet<Integer> list = new HashSet<Integer>();

    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(4);
    hset.put(1,list);

    System.out.println(hset.get(1));
    // the console prints "[1, 2, 3, 4]"
    list.clear();
    
    
    System.out.println(hset.get(1));
    // the console prints "[]"
    
}
```

I want to take user inputs for the HashSet, store them in the HashMap, then clear the HashSet to be used again by the user. But I need to use the same HashSet as there will be a loop.

Comment: You won't be able to reuse it.  You'll need to make a copy somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Put a new `HashSet` consisting of the elements of `list`.

```
hset.put(1, new HashSet<>(list));
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> hset = new HashMap<>();
        HashSet<Integer> list = new HashSet<>();

        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);
        hset.put(1, new HashSet<>(list));

        System.out.println(hset.get(1));
        // the console prints "[1, 2, 3, 4]"
        list.clear();

        System.out.println(hset.get(1));
        // the console prints "[1, 2, 3, 4]"
    }
}
```

On a side note, you need just `<>` on the right side i.e. instead of `new HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>`, you can simply write `new HashMap<>`.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter passing is done by reference in Java.

`HashSet` object in your `Hashmap` and `HashSet` object in the `list` variable are the same!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you do not clear the HashMap but rather add a new instance of the HashSet into the HashMap as your loop continues. like below.

```
public static void hash() {
HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> hset = new HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>()
int mapKey = 1;
//loop here , create the instance of HashSet for every loop operation
while(true){
HashSet<Integer> list = new HashSet<Integer>();

list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
list.add(4);
hset.put(mapKey,list);

System.out.println(hset.get(mapKey));
// the console prints "[1, 2, 3, 4]"
//list.clear();


System.out.println(hset.get(map.getKey));
// the console prints "[]"
mapKey++;
  }
}
```

The MapKey would be different for the different HashSets you will have.